# How do I generate UML diagram from code using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uml

I've looked online and haven't found a solution.

There is no "Architecture" tab inside Visual Studio 2015. All I want to do is generate a UML class diagram from existing code.

Comment: I think this feature is only available in VS2015 Ultimate...

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? According to the following to the information found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh871439.aspx#VersionSupport "Visual Studio is available in several versions. Not all of these provide support for the architecture and modelling tools." It's possible that your version does not provide the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

UML Diagrams are only available in the enterprise edition. Please check your VS edition.

[Compare Visual Studio 2015 Offerings](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)

Greetz Iki

Comment: Oh well that explains it. I dont have the enterprise edition :/

Comment: What is "Greetz Iki"?

Comment: @CodyGray This is what I found on Google regarding the phrase: `A term often used incorrectly by non English speaking people who insist on "greeting" people at the end of their message.` The source is Urban Dictionary. Google says the phrase may be of the Lithuanian language.

Comment: I have to confess that I'm not an English native speaker.. We use Greetz pretty often in text messages.. ^^ -> Not bad... Now I have also learned something about spoken languages ^^  -> Never use greetz^^